# I'm British, planning to visit the US; how long can I stay?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm British and looking to visit America for the first time. I have a friend who I will be staying with in Florida. I will be visiting under the visa waiver program. I intend on staying, if possible, for two months since I also have family around the U.S. who I want to visit, most being in Alabama.

I know under the visa waiver that you can visit for under 90 days but I do suffer from anxiety related to travelling. Am I allowed to stay for so long since I have people to stay with and will be visiting family?

Comment: Yes Yes Yes, satisfy the CBP official about your plan and enjoy your trip

Comment: @Hilmar, Which rules would be violated?

Comment: Two months is about 60 days, well within the 90 days permissible. Why would that be problematic? The OP certainly needs to have evidence that they can afford to stay in the USA that long, but there is no official rule that says staying for two months is banned but tolerated. It's allowed by the letter of the rules.

Comment: @Dennis: Sorry, I did the math wrong. Answer deleted

Answer (score 6):

Two months is about 60 days, well within the 90 days permissible under the VWP.

You need to have evidence that you can afford to stay in the USA that long without working, and it will help if you have a return ticket (not so much for having the ticket as for demonstrating that you have definite concrete plans for when to go back home).

In general, the more concretely you can describe your plans (where will you go, and when, who will you stay with, what are their contact details, what is their relation to you and why would they let you stay with them), the less risk do you run of trouble at the border.

What you need to **avoid** is giving the impression that you will be doing any practical favors for your hosts in exchange for getting a place to stay.  Even occasional babysitting, mowing the lawn, or other chores around the house could be construed as "work" if you meet a border guard who had a bad day and needs someone to take it out on.

Don't be unduly alarmed, though. *Most* visitors don't have trouble, and your plans are not so much out of the ordinary that you should expect any.

Comment: (Partially adapted from Robert Columbia's comment, but grew in the telling).